# Why does Git ask me to fill user credentials each time i pull or push changes?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I use Github and Git regularly and didn't face this problem until few days back where I had to enter my credentials twice before every push pull and such commands.
I tried these set of commands-

```
git config --global credential.helper store
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

and after trying many commands from stackoverflow I got this error.

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What can I do? Why did i face this problem suddenly in git?

Comment: You could try checking the [docs on ssh](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh), specifically [checking for existing SSH keys](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys) to ensure you do have one on your computer. If you do, you should then ensure that it is added to your GitHub SSH keys.

Comment: Credential helpers only apply to HTTP and HTTPS URLs, but it looks like you're using an SSH URL, which involves SSH public keys and isn't affected in any way by credential helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Since the credential helper won't help, as commented, try (assmuming a Linux-based OS)

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote -v
git ls-remote
```

Double-check at the `git remote -v` that origin is defined with an URL starting with `git@github.com:...`, meaning an SSH URL.

You will see more details when trying to use that URL with `git ls-remote`: what SSH key is looked for.